# 404 Badrequest is not hitting the OnActionExecuted method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

I am working in window service API and using .Net Framework 4.8
When I am sending request through postman if it correct URL it's hitting `OnActionExecuted` method, but if I given wrong URL means bad request at that time it's not hitting the `OnActionExecuted` method.

Same will applicable for `OnActionExecuting` method.

```
[RoutePrefix("mowfapi/peripheral/v1")]
 public class GetPeripheralTypesController : ApiController
 {
  [HttpGet]
  [Route("types")]
  public IHttpActionResult GetPeripheralTypes()
  {
          // My code
  }
 }


webApiConfig

 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
 {
     config.Filters.Add(new Logger());

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "DefaultApi",
    "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
   );
}

Logger

public class Logger : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        if (actionExecutedContext.Response.Content == null)
        {
            if (actionExecutedContext.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                var response = new MessageCode().GetStatusCode("400", "Bad request", "Request not supported");
                throw new HttpResponseException(actionExecutedContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, response));
            }
        }
        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Bad Request and Not Found are two different shoes. What do you mean by wrong url ?

Comment: wrong url means badrequest
My correct url is mowfapi/peripheral/v1/types
My wornng url is mowfapi/peripheral/v1/ty

Comment: that is not a bad request, bad request is when you call the correct url, but with wrong parameters. If your route does not exists, that is a 404, which means NotFound and it is ok not to enter to OnActionExecuted